# I can't complete the Proving honor quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've completed all the quests for Proving Honor, it's on completed quests but it's not actually completed. Return to Jorrvaskr diamond is not filled in. When I try to continue in the game asking for work he says he already gave me work when I am finished. I can't use console commands because I'm playing on a PS4, so how do I continue in the companions story. I did the ceremony where he swears loyalty to me but it still doesn't let me continue in the story.

Comment: Do you have a previous save you could jump to?

Comment: No after it happened I moved to other missions to see if it would fix itself later

Comment: Hmmm sounds like a glitch but I'll let someone else decide and answer. Sorry that happened man

Comment: @Nathaniel The tag you tried to add was not applicable, it is for a game called 'Glitch'

Comment: Did you participate in the initiation ceremony where Farkas swears loyalty to you?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you've encountered a known bug, with no known solution.

The [Bugs section of the Elder Scrolls Wiki page on this quest](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Proving_Honor#Bugs) says:

> The quest registers as completed in the journal, before being completed, making the next quest in the series impossible to initiate.

Since you're playing on PS4, you'll need to load a prior save. If you don't have one, then you'll have to either give up on the Companions quest line or start a new character.

This is an Elder Scrolls game. Make saves often, at key points.

Answer (score -2):

Ok my friend fond a way to fix this it is strange and takes some time but it works you have to make a new person and name him dadric then do the companion quests up to when you kill the silver hand and kill them with a silver sword head back to whiterun save it and go back to your world and you will have a new mission called family alum that is your next companion mission  I did this myself so I know it works

Comment: So your solution is to start a new game?

Comment: Did you create a second account to answer this? (Same name and account age) You are allowed to answer your own question, but there are issues regarding [multiple accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts)